# JAWS with table-formatted content

Tags: wpf, formatting, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I have a WPF chat application (based on RichTextBox), where each message in transcript is wrapped in its' own table element. When JAWS is used, it reads message text, and then says "Table".

Is there a way to prevent JAWS to say "Table" after reading each message?

Chat transcript view:

[image: image description]